# PHP Select and datetime format

Tags: php, sql, datetime, select

I have sql database with a table like this:

```
<pre>SubmissionId | FormId | DateSubmitted       | UserIp       |</pre>
<pre>1234         | 88     | 2014-07-25 21:47:45 | 192.168.1.5  |</pre>
<pre>1235         | 33     | 2014-07-25 17:22:21 | 10.90.1.64   |</pre>
<pre>1236         | 54     | 2014-07-25 09:43:12 | 192.168.1.32 |</pre>
<pre>1237         | 89     | 2014-08-20 11:13:44 | 10.88.45.5   |</pre>
```

The data types are:
**SubmissionId** is **Int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT**
**FormId** is **Int(11)**
**DateSubmitted** is **datetime**
**UserIp** is **varchar(15)**

The task is:
I have an associative array, from where I can get values ***FormId***, ***DateSubmitted*** and ***UserIp***. (array $data)
And using these values I have to find the ***SubmissionId***.

So I have a code like this:

```
    $res1 = $data['FormId'];
    $res2 = $data['DateSubmitted'];
    $res3 = $data['UserIp'];
    $query = "SELECT `SubmissionId` FROM `my_table1` WHERE `FormId` = '".$res1."' AND DATE(`DateSubmitted`) = DATE('".$res2."') AND `UserIp`='".$res3."'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $res11 = $db->loadResult();
//Update the value in another table
    $db->setQuery("UPDATE `my_table2` SET `FieldValue` = '".$res11."' WHERE `FieldName`='SubmissionNumber' AND `Name`='Test1'");
    $db->query();
```

So as you see the code gets the values of DateSubmitted and **gets only the date without time**. So the search has wrong result if I has several equal dates. I need to change the code to use the whole value of datetime. I need to use the time too.

So I don't know which function to use to make my SELECT query work properly.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
"`DateSubmitted` = '".$res2."'"
```

Alternatively, if you want to add some gray area there (instead of requiring to the second accuracy) you could do something like:

```
"`DateSubmitted` BETWEEN '".$res2."' - INTERVAL 60 SECOND AND '".$res2."' + INTERVAL 60 SECOND"
```

Make sure to escape your variables though, don't want sql injection :)

Edit:
If it's a free-form text box being used you might also want to add (php) strtotime and then date('Y-m-d H:i:s') to make sure it's formatted properly.

So `$res2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['DateSubmitted']));`